# Distributed Computing: Persistent Data Structures in Functional Programming versus Wait-Free Data Structures

Tags: distributed-systems, persistent-data-structure

Persistent (aka immutable) data structures in functional programming sidestep issues of shared memory mutual exclusion, and thus also issues such as data races that arise and which may be difficult to debug. But persistence requires more memory resources. On the other hand, wait-free versions of data structures guarantee that the crash of other threads will not affect the execution of a thread. Can anything be said about the circumstances that determine which solution is preferable?